# Problem to publish my updates in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, frontend, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a website in wordpress, but when I modified using BeaverBuilder, the changes appear just for me on my browser, but it is not published for other persons.

And I Applied to publish for the changes, but nothing happens.

Anyone can help me please?

I tried to clear the cash from my browser, flush the cash on wordpress, and use this sequence: save, done, and publish.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that you are saving and publishing your changes correctly within the BeaverBuilder interface. Sometimes, users forget to click the "Publish" button in the BeaverBuilder editor after making modifications.

Second, check if you have any caching plugins or server-side caching enabled, as this could be causing delays in updates being visible to others. Clearing browser cache is a good step, but also clear any caching on your WordPress site, and if you have a content delivery network (CDN) in place, clear its cache as well.

Lastly, if the issue persists, consider checking for conflicts with other plugins or themes that might be preventing proper updates. Deactivating other plugins temporarily and switching to a default theme can help identify if this is the issue.

If none of these steps resolve the problem, I'd say try consulting BeaverBuilder's support.